# SQL to return non-duplicate records

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a query that will sort by `Name` and `Year`, filter duplicates with higher years and return those records in a table. My data currently looks like this:

```
ID-----Name-----Year
1      Bob      2010
2      John     2014
3      Bob      2004
4      Eric     2005
```

The data should be primarily sorted by `Name` then secondarily sorted by `Year` in a descending fashion, like so:

```
ID-----Name-----Year
3      Bob      2004
1      Bob      2010
4      Eric     2005
2      John     2014
```

Then duplicate `Name` records should be filter returning only the lowest `Year` like so:

```
ID-----Name-----Year
3      Bob      2004
4      Eric     2005
2      John     2014
```

I've tried things like `SELECT DISTINCT` and `HAVING COUNT` but I can't seem to get it. Probably missing something simple. Any help?

Comment: Your first data example does not match your second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select ID, Name, Year
from (
    select ID, Name, Year, Rank() over (partition by Name order by year) as Rank
    from MyTable
) t
where Rank = 1
```

[SQL FIddle Example #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0393/1)

If you can't use `PARTITION`, you can do this:

```
select m.ID, m.Name, m.Year
from (
    select Name, min(Year) as MinYear
    from MyTable
    group by Name
) mm
inner join MyTable m on mm.Name = m.Name and mm.MinYear = m.Year
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0393/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Year) FROM table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Comment: probably wanna change Year to ASC as well

Comment: @user1301840 you're right, was reading the question ("`Year` in a descending fashion") rather than looking at the result.

Comment: Could you fix the query?  Remove "id" from the select.  Remove "year" from the order by.  The idea behind your solution is fine, but the query isn't.

Comment: default sort order is `ASC` in `order by` you dont need to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

assuming MySQL

```
select min(id), name, min(year)
from (
select distinct t1.id, t1.name, t2.year
from tbl t1, tbl t2
odrer by t1.name, t2.year
) T
group by name
```